# Firebase notification messages sent to iOS device are delayed

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I tried to send message from tool provided by Firebase in notifications section to a single iOS device, but the messages are delivered after approximately **7 minutes**. The message priority was set to **High**.
How ever if I send notifications using tools like **Easy APNs Provider**, the notifications are delivered immediately. Is there anything I have to do in case of Firebase, please suggest.

Comment: Firebase uses APNs to deliver the message so it's possible that during your first test APNs delayed the notification, while in the second test it didn't.
If you are able to reproduce this test consistently (firebase delayed, easy apns not) then please contact Firebase support: https://firebase.google.com/support/